# Missing keypoints from image

Tags: python, feature-extraction, opencv, orb

I'm trying to manually set 22 keypoints on an image so i can extract their features. For this task, i  create an array of keypoints with the coordinates i manually selected and pass the vector as a parameter in orb.compute and them draw the keypoints respectively.

My problem is that i set 22 points on different parts of an image, but it won't show more than 14 keypoints in the image.

Here's an example of what are the locations that i am expecting to draw 22 keypoints on:

[image]

What actually happens:

[image]

Points were changed a bit from one image to another, but it the coordinates in the code are what matters, the images are illustrative example of what im trying to do and what im getting.

Here's a reproducible version of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import skimage
import cv2
                imageList = skimage.io.imread("./a.png")  
                orb = cv2.ORB_create()
                key_points = [cv2.KeyPoint(65, 9, 10), <---- missing
                              cv2.KeyPoint(66, 12, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(62, 21, 10),
                              cv2.KeyPoint(60, 13, 10),
                              cv2.KeyPoint(67, 12, 10),
                              cv2.KeyPoint(107, 6, 10), <---- missing
                              cv2.KeyPoint(170, 10, 10),<---- missing 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(25, 60, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(60, 40, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(110, 35, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(170, 35, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(190, 60, 1), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(30, 95, 10), <---- missing
                              cv2.KeyPoint(60, 80, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(100, 105, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(120, 105, 10),
                              cv2.KeyPoint(160, 180, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(185, 95, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(25, 160, 10), <---- missing
                              cv2.KeyPoint(55, 160, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(155, 160, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(185, 160, 10), <---- missing
                              cv2.KeyPoint(65, 200, 10), <----- missing
                              cv2.KeyPoint(83, 186, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(128, 186, 10), 
                              cv2.KeyPoint(157, 197, 10) <---- missing]
                kp, des = orb.compute(imageList, key_points)
                kparray = cv2.drawKeypoints(imageList, kp, None, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS); 
                cv2.imshow("Image", kparray)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
```

So, for some reason i set all these 22 points that can be seen above, but when i run my code, it shows only 14, some are missing
I even tried printing the kp parameter in cv2.drawKeyPoints to make sure, even so:

```
[<KeyPoint 000002DF9DE83B40>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DF9DE83F90>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DF9DE83FC0>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DF9DE83F30>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DF9DE83DB0>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DFAB657030>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DFAB657B40>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DFAC1FED20>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DFAC1FE480>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DFAC1FEC90>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DFAC1FEDE0>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DFAC20D030>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DFAC20D060>, 
<KeyPoint 000002DFAC20D0C0>]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV ORB detector finds very few keypoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702433/opencv-orb-detector-finds-very-few-keypoints)

Comment: I can't say for sure the issue is the same, but the right answer is definetly on this thread, not on there. I tried that solution to make sure, i still got less points, besides there are no accepted answers, which means the issue was probably unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I had to drastically reduce the provided code in order to understand the issue. It may discourage people to help.

Additionally, you wrote :

> when I run my code, it shows only 14, some are missing I even tried printing the kp parameter in cv2.drawKeyPoints to make sure, even so:

So, as I understand it, it's not an issue of what OpenCV shows, it's an issue about keypoints ORB is able to compute.

So let me rephrase your question:

> In OpenCV why is ORB computation removing some keypoints.
>   Here is minimal code to reproduce:

```
import skimage
import cv2

imageList = skimage.io.imread("./a.png")
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
key_points = [cv2.KeyPoint(65, 9, 10), cv2.KeyPoint(66, 40, 10)]
kp, des = orb.compute(imageList, key_points)
print(len(kp))
```

> prints "1"

Therefore the answer may be found [in some other StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702433/opencv-orb-detector-finds-very-few-keypoints)

Changing the threshold, for instance, changed the results for me.

```
...
orb = cv2.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=1)
...
print(len(kp))
```

returns "2"

Unfortunately, I'm no ORB specialist, so you may have better results if rephrasing your question in order to drag ORB specialists attention instead of mine.

Good luck.

Comment: Changing the threshold as you did, brought up all the 22 points correctly. I will edit the question according to your suggestions, for future reference for whomever stumbles upon the same, but please, explain, how does this threshold parameter work, why am i reducing it?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same puzzle and can provide a partial answer to you. "Partial", because it doesn't fully explain the concrete example values you provided:

From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d0/d13/classcv_1_1Feature2D.html#ad18e1027ffc8d9cffbb2d59c1d05b89e) of the `compute()` method:

> keypoints, descriptors =   cv.Feature2D.compute(   images, keypoints[, descriptors]    )
> [snip]
> **keypoints** Input collection of keypoints. **Keypoints for which a descriptor cannot be computed are removed**. Sometimes new keypoints can be added, for example: SIFT duplicates keypoint with several dominant orientations (for each orientation).

(highlight mine).

So now why can a descriptor not be computed? In the case of ORB, the only possible answer I found in the source code is: If they are too close to the image border. Matter of fact, in [`orb.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5ac0712cf1f25af2224afd1776ca9476e39f85d8/modules/features2d/src/orb.cpp#L1120) :

```
KeyPointsFilter::runByImageBorder(keypoints, image.size(), edgeThreshold);
```

calls a method of `KeyPoints`, which simply removes everything that is closer to the margin than `edgeThreshold`, and in your case that will be ORB's default of 31.

That explains why some of your example key points go missing, but it does not explain why e.g. the second one `cv2.KeyPoint(66, 12, 10)` remains, since it is clearly closer to the margin than 31. Maybe there's a bug in your OpenCV version, or maybe I haven't fully understood what is going on.

Setting `edgeThreshold` to 1 helps, because it will not filter out any points unless they're smack on the border, *but* I'd advise against that, since the descriptor takes into account data from further away (which is controlled by the parameter `patchSize`), and I'm not sure, but I think if this happens to include data outside the image, then OpenCV just takes whatever happens to be at that memory address.

So my suggestion is: if you can't move your key points further into the image, then set `patchSize` to something that is as small as you can tolerate, and set `edgeThreshold` to half that plus some little margin.